# How to append a new column to a datatable and populate it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have an excel sheet consists of 4 fields and 10 records. I import them into a datatable, bind the same using SQLBulkCopy to a database table named 'SampleTable' already created, fetch the data stored from SampleTable and bind it onto a DataGridView for display. And...I know that it's a round-about process.

I just need some clarification at this point...

***Markup*:**

```
<asp:Label ID="sampleText" runat="server" Text="Upload the Excel Sheet"/><br /><br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="uploadClick" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadClick_Click" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

***CODE BEHIND*:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Pages_Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //region constants
    const string Gender = "Gender";
    //end region

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void uploadClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                //Upload and save the file
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                string conString = string.Empty;
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;

                }
                conString = string.Format(conString, fileLocation);
                using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                {
                    excel_con.Open();
                    string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

                    dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("City", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("State", typeof(string)) });

                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [ID], [Name], [City], [State] FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
                    {
                        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);


                        {


                        }
                    }


                    excel_con.Close();

                    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                    {
                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                        {
                            //Set the database table name
                            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.SampleTable";

                            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "City");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("State", "State");
                            con.Open();
                            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                            con.Close();
                            string message = "<script type='javascript'> prompt('Upload Complete');</script>";
                            Response.Write(message);
                            BindGrid();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID], [Name], [City], [State] FROM SampleTable"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- I want to add an extra column named **Gender** onto the **gridview** and have 2 radio buttons namely '**Male**' and '**Female**' on every row that has its ID as an even number.
- The value of the marked/selected radio button should, in turn, reflect in the database table.

> **Note:** I have 6 fields [incl. Gender(allows null)] already created in
>   the database table and I only need to fill the nulls with the values
>   assigned to the radio buttons in the gridview.

Comment: so what is the problem? you can easily do it using Disconnected ADO.Net achitecture i.e. using DataAdapter Fill method and update the data table with gender value and call update using same adapter.....you will get tons of article online

Comment: pardon me as i'm a dotnet newbie. kindly elaborate.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8af593/ado-net-dis-connected-architecture/ Read this

Comment: Create your columns manually in grid. Add one extra columns for gender. Bind all columns from using bouldfield except gender. Let me know if you have any difficulties.